# What is the difference in 'primary' calendarId and other calendarIds in Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

What primary as a calendarId is different than the other calendarId? Does other calendarIds contains some special polling event for Google calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Each user has a calendar associated with him/her by default, that calendar is recognised as the primary one. Every time you use the ***primary*** keyword in any API call, it will understand you're referring to your main calendar.  For any other calendar, you have to use its explicit Id.

[image]

In the diagram above you can have an idea about the calendars associations. For more info, you can check the [Overview of the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts). I hope this can answer your doubts.